# Jinja2 template find and replace string with new format

Tags: python, python-2.7, templates, django-templates, jinja2

I have a variable whose value is say `FileSystem`, I would like to get this printed as `file_system` in my template. 
Observe I am doing 2 things here: 
1. If the first letter of my string is capital letter then I am converting it to lower
2. If any of my other letters is in caps, then I am replacing it with underscore followed by its lower string format.
One more example would be converting `StackOverFlow` to `stack_over_flow`
How can I get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom jinja filter that takes your variable as input and allows you to apply your desired transformation.

Quoted from the official jinja help:

> Custom filters are just regular Python functions that take the left side of the filter  as first argument and the arguments passed to the filter as extra arguments or keyword arguments.

[jinja help section for custom filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#writing-filters)

Example:

```
def convert_to_snakecase(value):
    # convert your value here (lower case first letter + snake case)
    return formatted_value
```

Register your custom filter:

```
app.jinja_env.filters['convert_to_snakecase'] = convert_to_snakecase
```

Call your filter inside the template:

```
{{ my_variable|convert_to_snakecase }}
```